# Порядок при сортировке списка с помощью компаратора

Tags: java, коллекции

Имеем такой тестовый код. Предполагается, что созданные классы должны отсортироваться в первом случае (`LegComparator`) по наибольшему количеству ног, а во втором случае (`TailComparator`) по наличию хвостов.

В обоих случаях вывод (как я думал) должен быть: сначала собаки, а потом киви.

Однако получается все наоборот. Какую важную вещь я упустил?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Animal> any = new ArrayList<>();
        any.add(new Kiwi());
        any.add(new Dog());
        any.add(new Kiwi());
        any.add(new Dog());
        Collections.sort(any, new LegComparator());
        for (Animal animal : any) {
            System.out.println(animal);
        }
        System.out.println();
        Collections.sort(any, new TailComparator());
        for (Animal animal : any) {
            System.out.println(animal);
        }
    }

    static class Animal {
        protected int     countLeg = 2;
        protected boolean tail     = false;
    }

    static class Dog extends Animal {
        public Dog() {
            countLeg = 4;
            tail = true;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Dog";
        }
    }

    static class Kiwi extends Animal {
        public Kiwi() {
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Kiwi";
        }
    }

    static class LegComparator implements Comparator<Animal> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Animal first, Animal second) {
            if (first.countLeg == second.countLeg) {
                return 0;
            }
            return first.countLeg > second.countLeg ? 1 : -1;
        }
    }

    static class TailComparator implements Comparator<Animal> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Animal first, Animal second) {
            if ((first.tail && second.tail) || !(first.tail && second.tail)) {
                return 0;
            }
            return first.tail ? 1 : -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... в обоих случаях вывод (как я думал) должен быть - сначала собаки, а потом киви ...

Все методы, выполняющие сортировку сортируют по возрастанию. Т.е. сначала пойдут существа с меньшим числом ног (киви) затем с большим (собаки).

С точки зрения контракта `Comparator` это означает, что в отсортированном списке для индексов i, j таких, что i < j верно, что `comparator(a.get(i), a.get(j)) <=0`

Подробнее об этом можно почитать в документации [Collections.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) и  [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

P.S. `TailComparator` работает некорректно, т.к. выражение `(first.tail && second.tail) || !(first.tail && second.tail)` всегда `true`. Последовательность выводится в правильном порядке только потому, что алгоритм сортировки не меняет порядок элементов если не может корректно определить порядок. Если вы закомментируете первую сортировку, вторая перестанет работать.

Метод `compare` для хвостов можно реализовать, например, так:

```
public int compare(Animal first, Animal second) {
    return ((Boolean) first.tail).compareTo(second.tail);
}
```

Comment: "Все методы, выполняющие сортировку сортируют по возрастанию".. компаратор только средство выполнить эту самую сортировку

Answer (score 1):

Сортировка происходит по "возрастанию". При этом считается, что один элемент (`first`) "больше" другого (`second`), если `compare(first, second)` возвращает `1`.

Есть как минимум три варианта как изменить порядок элементов, чтобы собаки были до киви:

1. Заменить

   ```
   return first.countLeg > second.countLeg ? 1 : -1;
   ```

   На

   ```
   return first.countLeg > second.countLeg ? -1 : 1;
   ```

   Однако этот вариант не подойдёт, если вам нужно использовать этот компаратор и для сортировки в другом направлении.
2. Использовать `Collections.reverseOrder` для сортировки в обратном для данного компаратора порядке:

   ```
   Collections.sort(any, Collections.reverseOrder(new LegComparator()));
   ```

   Этот метод возвращает новый компаратор (не всегда, но в данном случае создастся новый), внутри которого в `compare(T t1, T t2)` происходит вызов оригинального компаратора как `compare(t2, t1)`.
3. Можно и вовсе не трогать компаратор, а разворачивать список после сортировки:

   ```
   Collections.sort(any, new LegComparator());
   Collections.reverse(any);
   ```

Однако это требует дополнительное (хоть и линейное) время на разворот списка.